# Using numpy arrays to count the number of points within the cells of a regular grid

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working with a large number of 3D points, each with x,y,z values stored in numpy arrays.
For background, the points will always fall within a cylinder of fixed radius, and height = max z value of the points.
My objective is to split the bounding cylinder (or column if it is easier) into e.g. 1 m height strata, and then count the number of points within each cell
of a regular grid (e.g. 1 m x 1 m) overlaid on each strata.

Conceptually, the operation would be the same as overlaying a raster and counting the points intersecting each pixel.
The grid of cells can form a square or a disk, it doesn't matter.

After a lot of searching and reading, my current thinking is to use some combination of numpy.linspace and numpy.meshgrid to generate the vertices of each cell stored within an array and test each cell against each point to see if it is 'in'. This seems inefficient, especially when working with thousands of points.

The numpy / scipy suite seems well suited to the problem, but I have not found a solution yet. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
I have included a few example points and some code to visualize the data.

```
# Setup
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Load in X,Y,Z values from a sub-sample of 10 points for testing
# XY Values are scaled to a reasonable point of origin
z_vals = np.array([3.08,4.46,0.27,2.40,0.48,0.21,0.31,3.28,4.09,1.75])
x_vals = np.array([22.88,20.00,20.36,24.11,40.48,29.08,36.02,29.14,32.20,18.96])
y_vals = np.array([31.31,25.04,31.86,41.81,38.23,31.57,42.65,18.09,35.78,31.78])

# This plot is instructive to visualize the problem
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='b', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Numpy n-dimensional histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand perfectly what you are looking for, but since every "cell" seems to have a 1m side for all directions, couldn't you:

- round all your values to integers (rasterize your data) probably with some `floor` function;
- create a bijection from these integer coordinates to something more convenient with something like:

  `(64**2)*x + (64)*y + z    #  assuming all values are in [0,63]`

  You can put `z` rather at the beginning if you want to more easely focus on height later
- compute the histogram of each "cell" (several functions from numpy/scipy or numpy can do it);
- revert the bijection if needed (ie. know the "true" coordinates of each cell once the count is known)

Maybe I didn't understand well, but in case it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Baruchel. It turns out the n-dimensional histograms suggested by @DilithiumMatrix provides a fairly simple solution to the problem I posted. After some reading, here is my current solution for anyone else that faces a similar problem.
As this is my first Python/Numpy effort any improvements/suggestions, especially regarding performance, would be welcome. Thanks.

```
# Setup
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Load in X,Y,Z values from a sub-sample of 10 points for testing
# XY Values are scaled to a reasonable point of origin
z_vals = np.array([3.08,4.46,0.27,2.40,0.48,0.21,0.31,3.28,4.09,1.75])
x_vals = np.array([22.88,20.00,20.36,24.11,40.48,29.08,36.02,29.14,32.20,18.96])
y_vals = np.array([31.31,25.04,31.86,41.81,38.23,31.57,42.65,18.09,35.78,31.78])

# Updated code below
# Variables needed for 2D,3D histograms
xmax, ymax, zmax = int(x_vals.max())+1, int(y_vals.max())+1, int(z_vals.max())+1
xmin, ymin, zmin = int(x_vals.min()), int(y_vals.min()), int(z_vals.min())
xrange, yrange, zrange = xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin, zmax-zmin
xedges = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xrange + 1), dtype=int)
yedges = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, (yrange + 1), dtype=int)
zedges = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, (zrange + 1), dtype=int)

# Make the 2D histogram
h2d, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x_vals, y_vals, bins=(xedges, yedges))
assert np.count_nonzero(h2d) == len(x_vals), "Unclassified points in the array"
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
plt.imshow(h2d.transpose(), extent=extent,  interpolation='none', origin='low')
# Transpose and origin must be used to make the array line up when using imshow, unsure why
# Plot settings, not sure yet on matplotlib update/override objects
plt.grid(b=True, which='both')
plt.xticks(xedges)
plt.yticks(yedges)
plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'ro')
plt.show()

# 3-dimensional histogram with 1 x 1 x 1 m bins. Produces point counts in each 1m3 cell.
xyzstack = np.stack([x_vals,y_vals,z_vals], axis=1)
h3d, Hedges = np.histogramdd(xyzstack, bins=(xedges, yedges, zedges))
assert np.count_nonzero(h3d) == len(x_vals), "Unclassified points in the array"
h3d.shape  # Shape of the array should be same as the edge dimensions
testzbin = np.sum(np.logical_and(z_vals >= 1, z_vals < 2))  # Slice to test with
np.sum(h3d[:,:,1]) == testzbin  # Test num points in second bins
np.sum(h3d, axis=2)  # Sum of all vertical points above each x,y 'pixel'
# only in this example the h2d and np.sum(h3d,axis=2) arrays will match as no z bins have >1 points

# Remaining issue - how to get a r x c count of empty z bins.
# i.e. for each 'pixel'  how many z bins contained no points?
# Possible solution is to reshape to use logical operators
count2d = h3d.reshape(xrange * yrange, zrange)  # Maintain dimensions per num 3D cells defined
zerobins = (count2d == 0).sum(1)
zerobins.shape
# Get back to x,y grid with counts - ready for output as image with counts=pixel digital number
bincount_pixels = zerobins.reshape(xrange,yrange)
# Appears to work, perhaps there is a way without reshapeing?
```

PS if you are facing a similar problem scikit patch extraction looks like another possible solution.